# IPython Kernel dies when trying to merge large list of dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, ipython, data-science

I'm trying to merge over 100 dataframes into a single dataframe using Pandas. When I try to merge them all, the iPython kernel dies.

I've already tried uninstalling and re-installing ipython and jupyter notebook as suggested [here](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/1892). I've run this code in Spyder and Jupyter Notebook and the kernel has died in both. I installed both through Anaconda Navigator on Mac OSX.

In the terminal, the only error I get is:

```
[I 09:09:34.341 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (1/5), keep random ports kernel 89dadad3-97c9-42c6-bcc9-9cedc4a6b6ff restarted
```

The code that I'm using to merge all the dataframes is

```
mega_df = reduce((lambda x, y: pd.merge(x, y, how = 'outer', on = col)), df_list)
```

I'd expect the result to be a dataframe with around 4500 rows and 12000 columns.

Comment: from your description, are they coming from flat files etc?

Comment: @MEdwin yes, all the files are text files delimited by tabs. I'm reading them in using pandas read_csv

Comment: Are you sure about the expected size? If you have even one duplicate in your merge column across all of the frames you're going to run into a memory error. 2^100 is massive. I suggest you look at `df.duplicated(subset=col).sum()`, and if this is non-zero you have an issue.

Comment: @ALollz yes, and I have many duplicate columns.

Comment: Then an outer merge is simply not possible in this case. You need to decide how to deal with this duplication, and likely de-duplicate the DataFrames or aggregate the duplicated rows together before you merge them.

Comment: do all the csv all have the same number of columns?

Comment: @ALollz Okay, thanks.

Comment: @MEdwin no, it varies by file.

Comment: okay, pandas merge will work, but you will need a lot memory that is why it crashes.

Comment: @ALollz you're right, I needed to use `pd.concat` instead of `pd.merge`. However, I'm still crashing the kernel. To solve this, I'm working on a function to concatenate all the dataframes as dictionaries, then convert the final dictionary to a dataframe.